# Visual Studio 2019 Data Sources not available

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, data-binding

I installed Visual Studio a few weeks.
Now I want to connect a Microsoft SQL table to my windows form project in C#.

Therefore I want to use the data source window.
But this window shows a problem.

Please have a look at my screenshot.

I installed Visual Studio already a second time.

> this window is not supported for the selected project. Steps to activate data binding can be found here.

[image: Data Source Window with problem]

Comment: Unfortunately the image of the error you have is in German, so I have no idea what it says. Please, however, don't post images of errors, put the text (in English) in your question.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for this mistake. I wrote the Text in my question now.

Comment: Are you creating a .NET Core project? Unfortunately, the `Data Source` is not supported in .NET Core yet. Refer to the note in [Add new data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/add-new-data-sources?view=vs-2019). Try to create a .Net Framework Winforms.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves my Problem. You made my day!